# Does git remote store deleted branches?

Tags: git, branch, commit

I was doing some experimentation to test my understanding of how git stores branches.

My understanding was that Git stores ALL commit hashes, so even if you delete a branch, the snapshot for that branch still exists under a commit hash, you can restore a deleted branch provided you know the hash.

To test this I tried the following (across two computers where I was pushing the repo to Github) :

Create a repo on GitHub

Computer 1 :

- clone repo
- create branch `experiment`
- add a file to `experiment` and push it to GitHub
- Make note of hash for the last commit to `experiment`
- delete `experiment` branch via :
- git push -d origin `experiment`
- git branch -d `experiment`

Computer 2 :

- clone repo
- Fetch/Pull
- try to restore the deleted branch `experiment`, checkout the hash I made a note of

Results

- On `computer 2` I get error: pathspec 'd168' did not match any file(s) known to git
- On `computer 1` it works.

So I guess my understanding is wrong.
you can only restore a deleted branch if you still have the info locally. i.e. the info relating to the deleted `experiment` branch only exists on Computer 1? not on the remote GitHub repo?

so cannot be used from Computer 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `git-clone` states: "Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch --remotes), and creates
and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch."

What this means is that when you clone the repository, it only copies the commits that are needed to make copies of all of the branches on the remote.  In your case, the commit `d168` is on the remote (unless github has a very aggressive garbage collection policy and has already deleted it), but it is not needed for any of the branches that currently exist (because you deleted the branch), so it is not copied during the fresh clone.

Try `git fetch origin d168....` to retrieve the commit from the remote.  If a commit is needed for a ref (loosely, it is the ancestor of some current branch tip or tag), then it will persist in the repository indefinitely.  If it is not needed for a ref, then at some point it may be deleted.  Typically, the default is to keep all commits for at least 30 days, so unless the garbage collection has been tuned to be more aggressive the commit should still be on the remote.

Comment: Didn't seem to work sadly, ```fatal: couldn't find remote ref <hash>```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't seem to work"?  Does the `fetch` fail?  After the fetch, can you `git show d168....` in the local repo (the fresh clone)?  Note that you probably need to specify the commit with more than 4 characters.

Comment: ah yes, that now works. Thanks. It appears you have to use the entire SHA when calling fetch

Answer (score 1):

Cloning only gets you the commits reachable from any ref (e.g. branch or tag). It doesn't download unreachable commits.

Some Git hosting platforms allow you to `fetch` commits if you know their hash, e.g. `git fetch origin 0123456789abcdef:experiment` (with the full commit hash). Or the web GUI allows you to create new branches referencing existing, but currently unreachable, commits.

Comment: Didn't seem to work sadly, ```fatal: couldn't find remote ref <hash>```